# Reshaping a 2D array of images using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape `(10, 10, 1024, 1024, 3)`. This represents an 10x10 grid of images, each of shape `(1024, 1024, 3)` (1024x1024 color images). I want to reshape this into one array of shape `(10*1024, 10*1024, 3)`, where the 1024x1024 patch of pixels in the upper left of the new image corresponds to the `[0, 0]` index of my original array. What's the best way to do this using numpy?

Comment: Hi, what have you tried before looking for the "best" way?

Comment: I tried `arr.reshape(10*1024, 10*1024, 3)`, but the order seems off, as the output image is muddled.

Comment: I imagine some combination of `resize` and `swapaxis` will get the desired result, but I don't have a great intuition for these functions yet.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job: `np.swapaxes(arr,1,2).reshape(10*1024, 10*1024, 3)`. Note that `swapaxis` generates an array of shape `(10, 1024, 10, 1024, 3)`.